# Is SecurityManager a full security solution?

Tags: java, security

Can I avoid third party code from creating new threads, starting new VMs, or leaking data using a customized SecurityManager?

Comment: Yes, using e.g. `Runtime.exec`. A `SecurityManager` can be used to restrict the execution of external processes.

Comment: Any Turing complete language can create a VM and there's nothing you can do about it... I reckon OP just wanted to disable running **any** external program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thread creation results in a call to `securityManager.checkAccess(g)` where `g` is a `ThreadGroup`. That in turn requires `SecurityConstants.MODIFY_THREADGROUP_PERMISSION`.

The only way to create a new JVM instance is to start a new process. That will require `SecurityConstraints.FILE_EXECUTE_ACTION`.

So, if your SecurityManager raises an exception for both of those permissions, your first 2 cases are covered.

You'll need to qualify what constitutes "leaking data". Is the concern over accidental or deliberate leaks? Is the concern the untrusted code accessing data, or the untrusted code's data being accessible by other threads, classes, etc?

Answer (score 3):

Nothing much is a full security solution (unless you ask salesmen).

I'd say the SecurityManager can control all this (as was said you don't necessarily need a custom security manager, you can configure a lot simply through a policy). Controlling threads, process execution, enforcing access to private data and network connections (3rd party app sending private data to your competition, etc) - that's what the SecurityManager is for.

However, you need to weigh how much security you need. Consider that with every Java security update Sun fixes maybe 3-4 vulnerabilities ([Java 6u15 as an example](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/webnotes/6u15.html#bugfixes-6u15)) in the Java security sandbox. These updates take place about 3-4 times per year (or took, don't know what the Oracle acquisition will do to that). So any of these ~12 annual vulnerabilities could cause your data to be leaked.

If my secrets were very valuable to someone else, I personally would not trust SecurityManager to control potentially malicious 3rd party code running in my environment. (I don't have valuable secrets and I already don't trust Java running in my browser under the SecurityManager to behave.)

Comment: The original question said "export" rather than "leak". This seems to imply that the issue is whether untrusted code can publish data it has access to externally. As it turns out, getting rid of all covert channels on the internet is a little tricky.

Comment: I see. Reading that and the other questions by (the other) Tom. If he's worried about the final user altering the policy file, I may have misunderstood his scenario.

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly do the first two things.  However, i'm not sure what you mean by "leaking data".

Note, you don't need a customized SecurityManager, you just need a custom policy file.

Comment: But isn't the policy file passive of modifications by the final user?

Comment: I don't really understand what that question means.